# In realm, how to query from a RealmList (Android)

Tags: android, realm

Check out following classes:

```
class Person{
    int id;
    String name;
    RealmList<Mail> mails;
    ...
}

class Mail{
    int id;
    String content;
    ...
}
```

I have a `Person` object (ie: `mPerson`) and I am accessing all `Mail`s of the `Person` object by `mPerson.getMails()`. Till here everything is cool.

---

**Here is the question**: Is there way to query over the returned list such as `findAllSortedAsync()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `RealmList.where()` to create a query. You can find document [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html#where--)

For example:

`RealmList<Mail> mails = person.getMails();
RealmResults<Mail> results = mails.where().equalTo("id", 1).findAllSortedAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

```
    RealmResults<Contact> contacts = mRealm.where(Contact.class).findAll();

    int size = contacts.size();
    for (int i = 0;i<size;i++){
        Contact contact = contacts.get(i);
        RealmList<EMail> eMails = contact.emails;
    }
```